# NodeJS + CloudSQL Postgres - Connection terminates randomly

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, knex.js

We are using Google CloudSQL Postgres and it seems our backend API keeps getting disconnected from CloudSQL at random intervals (between 1-4 days). Connections are made directly to the CloudSQL Postgres Instance IP address.

Could it be that CloudSQL disconnects idle connections? We have health checks on our API that runs a simple `SELECT` against the database every minute.

We are using [`knex`](https://knexjs.org/) which—as far as I know—uses [`tarn`](https://github.com/vincit/tarn.js) to manage connections.

Are there any recommended settings for connection pooling with CloudSQL Postgres?

Comment: Can you share the logs for the instance covering the time interval when these connection terminations occur?

Comment: @Yurci Way ahead of you :) The logs were empty for the CloudSQL instance for those time periods.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any recommended settings for connection pooling with CloudSQL Postgres?

no, there is not.

Anyways knex should notice, when connection is closed by server and discard it automatically from connection pool, thus hiding the disconnection from end user.

Comment: Yeah that was my understanding as well, so I don't know why this is happening. I also get "Transaction is complete, run with DEBUG=knex*" — these occur at random times, and I think it might be a result of the connection dropping as well.

Comment: To be clear, this only happens in CloudSQL. I can run everything locally for days with no problem.

Comment: Our API machines are on GCloud Compute Engine which has a default TCP connection timeout of 10 minutes. If that happens, does Knex handle it?

Comment: You can set the [TCP keepalive](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/diagnose-issues#compute-engine) to get over connection timeout.

Comment: CloudSQL doesn't disconnects idle connections. Will you try TCP keepalive and update your post?